# Access String Array outside of two loops

Tags: java, database, arrays, loops, derby

I have an array of Strings created inside of a while loop nested inside a for loop.  This has to do with creating an array from a column of strings in Derby but I will leave out some stuff for simplicity's sake.

The reason I am not providing the full code is because the problem is very specific.  I am having no problems whatsoever with my database, resultset, statements, or queries.  It's just accessing the array outside of the two loops.

```
//in the class, 
private int rowCount; //Count of the rows in my column of strings
public String stringArray[];


//in the method I am using
public void myMethod() { 
    rowCount = 4; //In my code it actually counts it, lets say its four though.
    stringArray = new stringArray[rowCount]; //set  
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
         while (rs.next()/*rs is simply a result set of a statement executeQuery to select the correct table*/)
         {
             stringArray[i] = rs.getString(2); //2 is the column number in the table
         }
    }
//Need to access stringArray here.  When I try to print out values, it always prints out as null.
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: you can access the array outside the loops. Your problem is elsewhere, not with the reading of the values

Comment: try printing the string **inside** your loop.(or using a debugger to see what's actually being put in the string).  I'll bet that your values are null there too

Comment: Are you sure your loop actually fills anything? For instance, is it really `.getString(2)` that you want? How do you "print out values"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's something wrong with your nested loops. For each row (each value of i / each execution of the outer loop), you iterate through your whole result set and overwrite `stringArray[i]` (i not chaning) many times.

When you get to the second row (i.e. i is 1 or higher), rs.next() will already be false, since you tranversed the whole rs in the first iteration of the outer loop.

Maybe you just need to replace your inner loop `while(rs.next())` with a single call to `rs.next()`

Comment: I actually solved it by changing the loop to this:

    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount && rs.next(); i++) {
        stringArray[i] = rs.getString(2);
    }

worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps in your actual code, where you say:

```
rowCount = 4; //In my code it actually counts it, lets say its four though.
```

you are performing the count of the rows by doing something like:

```
for( rowCount = 0; rs.next(); rowCount++ ) { }
```

If you're doing something like that, then you've basically read all the rows already during the counting phase, and when you try to re-process the rows later the rs.next() method simply returns false since it's already read all the rows.

Of course, I'm just guessing...